# Spring Batch JdbcCursorItemReader not reading all records in Jboss EAP6 cluster

Tags: java, spring-batch

**Spring batch** is configured with in memory **JobRepository** i.e. **MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean**. 
It use **JdbcCursorItemReader** for fecting records from an Oracle view. Jboss non-XA datasource is used from JNDI.
The records are processed via remote chucking mechanism to distrute load accross JBOSS cluster.

The job is launched via a webserivce call. And the webserivce is deployed on all the nodes in the cluster.
Externally the webservice call is load balanced.

Identical pacakage (**EAR**) is deployed on all nodes of **JBoss** cluster.

If the job is launched on node 1 of jboss cluster, all records are read from the item reader & processed (total 400 records).
However, if the same job get launched on node 2 of jboss cluster only 320 records are read from the item reader & processed.

I'm unable to explain the difference of 80 records as there are no exception in logs and I also tried to double check by taking a **count(*)** from the oracle query before I launched the jboss.

Are there any issues with spring batch and jboss cluster? I can run test and get additional details as requested.

All records should be read from the view irrespective of the node where the job is launched

Comment: Have you confirmed that both nodes have the same datasource configured?

Comment: Yes. Both nodes have same datasource configured.